# Source that 2nd day Yom Tov is spiritually needed for those outside Israel

Tags: sources-mekorot, eretz-yisrael, yom-tov, golus-exile

I heard a view that those outside Israel **need** a second day Yom Tov in order to achieve the spiritual status that those in Israel can achieve in one day. I would like to see the source of this statement.

Comment: Rav Zevin discusses this in his Le'Or HaHalacha

Answer (score 3):

Sources found in Yalkut Yosef Yom Tov/Chol Hamoed page 74:

1. [Emunat Chachmim פרק כט](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31361&st=&pgnum=143&hilite=)
2. [Chidah in Petach Enayim Ketuvot 110b](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40654&pgnum=451)
3. [Ruach Chaim Pilagi Siman תצו](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37782&st=&pgnum=155)
4. [Rav Paalim Chelek א Kuntres Sod Yesharim Siman ו](https://www.sefaria.org/Responsa_Rav_Pealim%2C_Volume_I%2C_Sod_Yesharim.6.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
5. [Shulchan Aruch Harav (מהדורה תנינא סימן א סעיף ח)](https://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh1/1/1/8.htm)
6. [Shu"t Beit Avi Chelek ה end of Siman נח](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=893&st=&pgnum=486&hilite=)

Comment: Thank you. Could you possibly provide a link to any of the sources? I have had real difficulty.

Comment: מה"ת == מהדורה תנינא == second edition

Comment: @Menachem, thanks

Comment: @Menachem is the מהדורה תנינא of HG"R Zalman's Shulchan Aruch a separate volume or appendix? Of if I find an edition printed nowadays it's going to be the second edition? Usually when I've seen the phrase מהדורה תנינא it's in the context of shutim and refers to completely different works, more akin to "Volume II" than the literal meaning of "Second Edition."

Comment: @Avraham - when compiling the Baal HaTanya's Shulchan Aruch for print, his sons found the beginnings of a second edition. It covers the first 4 chapters, and they published it before the regular edition of his Shulchan Aruch: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25072&st=&pgnum=31&hilite=

Comment: @Menachem oh interesting. I never knew that. I must say, I haven't seen the Yalkut Yosef inside but this passage does not seem to me to say chutz l'aretz has yom tov sheini because they need more  help to reach the kedusha of yom tov. Rather, I think his point is that since yom tov sheini is observed in chutz l'aretz it actually becomes yom tov and has kedusah and you shouldn't say that "cosmically" it isn't really yom tov; just like we don't say that when you daven shacharit in America it spiritually counts as mincha because it's afternoon in Israel.