# Washing a newborn's hands in the morning - identifying sources

Tags: sources-mekorot, netilat-yadayim-washing, chinuch-education

I am currently looking at the concept of *Negel Vasser* - washing hands in the morning, and how it pertains to chinuch.

There is an apparent machlokes amongst the poskim with there being those who say:

1. One does it before the age of chinuch (e.g. [Pri Megadim, Mishbetzos Zahav 4:7](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41248&st=&pgnum=38) [Mishnah Berurah 4:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.4.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), the [Chida](https://www.sefaria.org/Moreh_BeEtzba.60.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en))
2. One does it from the age of chinuch (e.g. Pri Megadim, Eishel Avraham, Halichos Shlomo 20:25)

However there as an additional option (a sub-category of point 1 if you like) of those who say even from when the child is a newborn. This approach is attributed to the Ben Ish Chai and the Shulchan Aruch HaRav. It is mentioned [here](https://torah.org/torah-portion/weekly-halacha-5766-lechlecha/) (footnote 6) and [here](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Netilat_Yadayim_upon_Waking_Up#cite_note-62)

The sources point to either the [Ben Ish Chai, Toldos 10](https://www.sefaria.org/Ben_Ish_Hai%2C_Halachot_1st_Year%2C_Toldot.10?lang=en) (as alluded to in the [Peninei Halacha](https://www.sefaria.org/Peninei_Halakhah%2C_Women%27s_Prayer.5.9.2?ven=Peninei_Halakhah,_English_ed._Yeshivat_Har_Bracha&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) - this is clear in the text.

**Questions**

1. It also points to the Ben Ish Chai via the [Kaf HaChaim 4:23](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.4.23.1?lang=bi&lookup=%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA&with=Shulchan%20Arukh,%20Orach%20Chayim&lang2=en) but I cannot see any mention of the Ben Ish Chai's approach?
2. The [Shulchan Aruch HaRav 4:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh_HaRav%2C_Orach_Chayim.4.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) is also mentioned ("one should be careful starting after the brit milah to wash his son's hands") as one who says a newborn's hands should be washed, but again it doesn't seem to be mentioned in the text?

Please can anyone help to locate the exact wording in the source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so either Sefaria has different numbering or the websites made a mistake? But the Kaf HaChaim link on Sefaria is the one beforehand [4:22](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.4.22.1?vhe=Kaf_Hachayim,_Orach_Chayim_vol._I-IV,_Jerusalem_1910-1933&lang=bi)

> וכתב בן א"ח שם אות יו"ד בשם החס"ל דמנהג זה הוא סגולה טובה לקטנים כדי שיגדלו בטהרה ויהיו גידולי הקדש

If anyone knows what is the correct mareh makom - please let me know in the comments.

Ok also found [Shulchan Aruch HaRav](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh_HaRav%2C_Orach_Chayim%2C_Second_Edition.4.2?vhe=Kehot_Publication_Society&lang=bi) - also confused about the numbering, there seems to be two editions on Sefaria?

> נהגו להקל בנגיעת הקטנים שלא הגיעו לחינוך לפי שגמר ועיקר כניסת נפש הקדושה באדם הוא בי"ג שנים ויום א' לזכר וי"ב לנקבה שלכן נתחייבו אז במצות מן התורה ונעשו בני עונשים ותחלת כניסת נפש זו הקדושה היא בחינוך לתורה ולמצות שחייבו חכמים לחנך (גם במצות מילה **ולכן הנזהר מנגיעת הקטן מיום המילה ואילך** קדוש יאמר לו)

Comment: ok please excuse my ignorance - I didn't realise that there was a מהדורה בתרא (a second edition) to the shulchan aruch harav - and the said source of the shulchan aruch harav I was looking for was in the later edition.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/134186/source-that-2nd-day-yom-tov-is-spiritually-needed-for-those-outside-israel/134190?noredirect=1#comment446711_134190 — both mahadurahs are printed together, the second edition is only the first few chapters.

Comment: Thanks so much @Menachem